# LinkedIn API likes/shares/comments

Tags: linkedin-api

We have been trying to pull in like/comments for LinkedInposts that have been made by our application but it seems we are getting an error message. I am posting this on behalf of my developer. We have these products enabled.

Share on LinkedIn, Sign in with LinkedIn and Marketing Developer Platform

We have these permissions:

```
r_organization_social
r_1st_connections_size
r_ads_reporting
r_emailaddress
rw_organization_admin
r_liteprofile
r_basicprofile
r_ads
rw_ads
w_member_social
```

In trying to determine what might be happening my developer seems to think we must have r_member_social but seems to be a restricted permission per the LI faq.

> "How do I get access to r_member_social?
> r_member_social is a closed permission, and we are not accepting access requests this time due to resource constraints. Learn more about available Marketing APIs and permissions."

But in looking into this my thinking is that we should be able to get any likes/comments from posts that WE have made on behalf of an authenticated user via `r_organization_social`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api?tabs=http Check this

Comment: What error message are you getting?  If relevant, please add a minimal bit of code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: My developer provided me with this. 

"serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-handleString /clientAwareMemberHandles",
    "status": 403

 I guess it really is that we need the r_member_social permission but that seems to not be available. It seems quite strange that you can't get the likes from a post you made on behalf of your clients.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough permissions to access the post as r_member_social is needed for it, and currently it is restricted by linkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

The r_organization_social permission is used to Retrieve the organization's posts, comments, reactions, and other engagement data of the authenticated user.

It is something, that suppose your authenticated member has a page on LinkedIn and then This permission is used to get the data of the post that are from the organization page. It does not allow you to the data of the simple post that you post as the user.

More detail about the permissions can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/getting-access).

r_member_social is needed for it, and currently, it is restricted by LinkedIn. There are just providing w_member_social access. You can check that as well by selecting your app from My Apps, navigating to the Products tab, going to the Marketing Developer Platform product, and clicking on view endpoints. then you will be able to see the permissions available.
[image]

Alternatively, you can explore this [marketing documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/?view=li-lms-2022-11) more.

Answer (score 0):

As colleagues stated in their posts that the permission "r_member_social" is temporarily withdrawn.

**One trick way:
How to get analytic for post when you have r_member_social scope**

When you create a post, you get response 201 and empty content.
However, in the header at the key location you have that post id.
You extract it and save it, later you can use it to get analytics on it.

```
    var client = new HttpClient();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", {YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN});
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Linkedin-Version", "202308");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Restli-Protocol-Version", "2.0.0");
    
    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts", content, cancellationToken);

    var postId = response.Headers.Location?.OriginalString;        
    postId = postId?.Replace("/", "").Replace("posts", "").Replace("%3A", ":");
    // urn:li:share:7122594746383953921
```